# Powershell get extension files within a given path

Tags: powershell

The main idea of this post is that, given a path to folder or disk. Then powershell will search all file and folder inside this path and list all the extension file current stored in this path (docx, xlsx, jpg,...)

The final results will be stored in csv file.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Hi, welcome Stackoverflow, we are willing to help you, but as Jeff mentioned, don't rely we will make your homework, that's not how SO works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a little fix in the svanzundert solution

```
$Folder = "C:\Temp\"
Get-ChildItem $Folder | Select Extension -Unique | Where-Object{$_.Extension -ne ""} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\YourCSV.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

You just have to use -Unique parameter in the Select-Object

Comment: Oh thanks. Now it doesn't repeat same extension anymore!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this, but could be I misunderstood your question.

```
$Folder = "C:\Temp\"
Get-ChildItem $Folder | Select Extension | Where-Object{$_.Extension -ne ""} | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\YourCSV.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I want! But it still have a small problem is that if I have 2 pdf file, it will list 2 extension pdf and pdf in CSV file?

Comment: There should be something like `Get-Unique` @ABCD check [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-unique?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 0):

For sure there will be better ways, like use filter to get from childs files onlz but zou can do something like follows:

```
#will load directory content
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\fooo\Documents\" 

#empty array for extensions preparation
$extensions = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)

#iterate over items= files and directories
for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) {
    #print all (once by one of course)
    #Write-Host $files[$i].FullName
    #print extension only
    #Write-Host $files[$i].Extension

    #store extensions by unique, if its a file
    if( ($files[$i].GetType().Name -eq "FileInfo" ) -and !$extensions.Contains($files[$i].Extension) ){
        $extensions.Add($files[$i].Extension)
    }
}

Write-Host $extensions
```

my output:

```
.gitattributes .gitignore .mailmap .yml .cmd .fsx .sh .md .dependencies .lock .sln .DotSettings
```